# Ajax CSRF problem in Django 1.3

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

According to django documentation, for ajax post request in 1.3 (at least with Jquery), we just need to add this [snippet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) to main js file. This snippet get csrftoken from cookies, and then set up it for all ajax request. That's work, but what if csrftoken don't exist in cookies? I thought render_to_response and render both automatically checks if csrftoken in sessions, and set it for us, if token not there. But they are not. So, i need to implement it by myself? Or maybe there is another way to handle ajax csrf protection?

Answer (score 11):

When there is no form on a page that is already using {% csrf_token %}, the cookie will not be sent. Therefore, as you noted, you will get an error when you attempt to use Ajax on such a page. This will lead to erratic behavior if you have a site with a mix of pages with various combinations of forms and ajax posts.

This has already been reported and fixed: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15354

The solution in the patch, will should roll out with 1.3.1, is the ensure_cookie_csrf decorator. That decorator does not exist in 1.3 or 1.2.5

No need to wait, however. Just add this line to any view which contains AJAX posts a CSRF form:

```
request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
```

Example:

```
def calculator(request):
    request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
    return render_to_response('calc.html', {'form': CalcForm()})
```

FYI - this is exactly what that decorator does.

Comment: According to [CSRF Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie), the ensure_cookie_csrf decorator is new for Django 1.4.

Comment: Yup, the ensure_csrf_cookie decorator landed in Django 1.4. Unfortunately not in 1.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Your cookie will only contain the CSRF token, if either the template tag `{% csrf_token %}` was used in the template to generate the request, or if you call `get_token` (with the `request` object as argument) from `django.middleware.csrf`.

The `get_token` function sets metainformation on the `request` object that in turn tells the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` middleware to set the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

As for Ajax, you should pass the csrf token with every request. For jQuery, I use the following code:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if(!options.crossDomain) {
        if(options.data) {
            options.data += "&";
        } else {
            options.data = "";
        }
        options.data += "csrfmiddlewaretoken={{csrf_token}}";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that I've found to get around this is by using a preexisting form as a starter point for your AJAX data.

```
<form id="ajax_form" stye="display: none;">{% csrf_token %}</form>
```

Then you can use this in your JavaScript via JQuery's Serialize function:

```
var data = $('#ajax_form').serialize();
data += "&mydata=69";
```

You can even use hidden fields within that hidden form so that you don't have to use string concatenation to built your POST data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the @csrf_protect decorator, make sure that both the view with the form and the view that the data is being posted to use the decorator.

I had a similar issue. I only had @csrf_protect on the post view which worked fine testing locally but when i went live o got a 403 verification failed issue adding the decorator tot he page view fixed this